# Find a basis for $\mathbb{R} ^5$ containing the given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ that contains the vectors $(1,-1,1,-1,0)$, $(-1,-1,1,-1,0)$ , $(-1,1,1,-1,0)$.

I think I need to find two more vectors so that the five vectors are all linearly independent and spans $\mathbb{R}^5$, but I am not sure how can I do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first thing you should do is check that the set of three vectors given is a linearly independent set.  Once you do that, if they *do* form a linearly independent set, then, as you said, you should find two more vectors such that the set of 5 vectors forms a linearly independent set.  Do you know how to check that the set of three vectors given is linearly independent?

Comment: @user46944 I have checked that the three vectors given is a linearly independent set, but I don't know how to find the other two vectors.

Comment: Ok, well notice that all three vectors have $0$ in their last coordinate.  At least one of your new vectors will have to have a non-zero entry in the last coordinate (and any such vector with a non-zero entry in the last coordinate will form a linearly independent set with the three vectors given).  That should help you find a fourth vector.  Do you think you can find the fifth?

Comment: @Lucy One quick way is to look at your current set of vectors and determine if one of the components of _all_ the vectors is _missing_..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All  you have to do is check all of the $e_i$ vectors - that is the elementary vectors $(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),\dots(0,0,0,0,1)$. Since these are $5$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$, you know two of them must be linearly independent from the $3$ vectors you have already.